# css for mobile but for landscape mode?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm using special css for mobile devices but set the max-device-width to 480 px (i don't know whether this is standard size or not). however, when my screen is in landscape mode width is actually greater than 480 px so this mobile.css file didn't load.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="/media/css/mobile.css" type="text/css" />
```

What is the proper way to handle this situation... ? please help!

---------------------------- Update -------------------------------------------

So, this works fine, but seems like mobile devices are doing weird thing when the page is loaded initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've found works. I'm currently developing a site for iOs/Android devices and I'm using 670px:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=670, initial-scale=0.45, minimum-scale=0.45"/>
```

I also put everything in a div with the following styling

```
#mainDiv
{
        max-width:670px; 
        margin-right: auto; 
}
```

This fits the mobile viewport fine for portrait and, because the div is left-aligned, landscape too.

Comment: so you are saying i should change 480 to 670?

Comment: Yes http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakeYourWebsiteMobileAndIPhoneFriendlyAddHomeScreenIPhoneIconsAndAdjustTheViewPort.aspx

Comment: that worked! But what about tablets like ipad or some android tablets?

Comment: if you detect for tablets you could make that max-width bigger